# text color coding in Netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, editor, el

I have a pretty annoying issue with text highlighting on my EL statements.

[image: screenshot]

I have scrolled through every field in the Options/Fonts&Colors/Syntax Control Panel three times, paying extra attention to the Expression Language options and I can not find the parameter that controls the white background of the whole ${initParam.productImagePath} expression statement.

Comment: Maybe I should report this as a bug.

Comment: What's the file type? Is it a xml file, jsp or a gsp page? The gsp categorie is missing some color entries but you can possibly manually edit/copy/paste the appropriate xml file entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking under Fonts&Color -> Syntax.  Then select the language and check all the color settings there.

**UPDATE**

I would add that sometimes the settings are inherited... it can be really hard to find which setting controls the color.

You can save the color settings exporting ("Export" button) then change every setting under "Expression Language" just to see if it changes.

Also, you can look through all colors in all languages and tabs until you find the color that matches the one you are seeing in the editor.

I'm guessing you may have done all this already, but I want to be sure I give the most complete answer I know of just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also check the entries in the Fonts&Colors Highlighting-Tab?

Your image shows that the white expression is not in the current selected line, so my guess is that you have enabled "highlight Search" (small Editor Toolbar). Another guess: if you are using the jVi Plugin, there's another highlight search parameter in jVi's settings dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the try but that wasn't it. Every expression statement in the document from the $ to the } gets the light background, unless the line is selected.